# Use jQuery Mobile 1.0.1 with jQuery 1.7.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, refactoring

I'm on the process of refactoring a web application developed in jQuery Mobile. The task consists  in divide a single html file that contains several `data-role="page"` to multiple html files.

The pages will be loaded to `data-role="content"` through AJAX. The problem is that all attached events will now have to be `live()` / `delegate()` / `on()` instead of `bind()`.

The stable version of jQueryMobile is 1.0.1 and the  jQuery core recomended the for this version is 1.6.4, which means that `on()` is not available.

My question is: how safe is to use jQuery Mobile 1.0.1 along with jQuery 1.7.2?

Comment: Try it with jquery 1.7.1, 1.7.2 still has some issues with jQuery Mobile.

Comment: How about updating to [jQuery Mobile 1.10 RC1](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/02/28/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-1-0-rc1/), which gets you jQuery 1.7.1 compat?

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL the problem is that jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 it's still the first release candidate. I haven't tried yet, so I don't know how stable is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest stable jQMobile is meant to work with jQ 1.6.4...

Looks like (in line with the above comments) 1.1.0 should work with 1.7.x

[jQ Mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/download/), although I rememeber reading about this specifically

Gimme a minute I'll try to find the exact reference.

Comment: http://www.jquerymobile.com/download

Comment: The example on the bottom of the page uses jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 RC1.

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/, if you search for "1.6.4" you'll find some info.

Comment: @Jasper do you use jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 RC1? How stable is it?

Comment: @Diogo I haven't had many issues with it and whenever I do it's minor, like a CSS glitch or something. Functionally, it may not be ready for production but if your developing a site I'd go ahead and use it. The fixed headers/footers work really well even in browsers that don't support `position : fixed`.

Comment: I've been using 1.1RC-1 in development as well and it works great. I imagine by the time I am finished the final version will be out.